# rm -f files starting with a digit

Tags: rm

I've accidentally redirected the output of a CSV file to my directory.  How can I `rm` only the files that start with a number, and leave the files that start with a letter intact?

```
mymachine$ ls
71.24         README.md        30            4.29
8             filter.sh        42.81         5.58         
8.36          purchases.csv    1,208.8       100          
16.7          2.56             21.78         269.96
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$ rm [0-9]*
```

Remember you can always use `echo` with any globbing arguments prior to letting `rm` run with them.

```
$ echo [0-9]*
100 1,208.8 16.7 21.78 2.56 269.96 30 42.81 4.29 5.58 71.24 8 8.36
```

After running the `rm` command above:

```
$ ls
filter.sh  purchases.csv  README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can also easily use `find` combined with the `-regex` and `-delete` options.

In the folder, first test your file selection:

```
$ find . -regex "[^/]+/.*[0-9]+"
```

Then add the `-delete` option:

```
$ find . -regex "[^/]+/.*[0-9]+" -delete
```

Your files are now deleted:

```
$ ls
filter.sh  purchases.csv  README.md
```

Always check your selection first, since using the `[^/]+/.*[0-9]+` regular expression will select any file containing a number at the end (e.g. `md5` or `hdf5`).

Please note that `find` automatically process subdirectories as well. If you don't want this add `-maxdepth 1` before the regular expression.

For OS X add the `-E` option.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you [edit] it so that the regex starts with `^[0-9]` to explicitly match filenames beginning with a digit (as per the question).

Comment: The problem is that `find` adds the relative path to the output, so in this case a `./`, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: That would remove files whose name _ends_ in at least one digit (equivalent to the standard `-name '*[0-9]'`) which is not what is being asked for here. That would also look for those files in subdirectories which is not asked for either.

Comment: That's what I indicated in my answer already.

Comment: But you're right about the subdirectories, I added it to my answer.

Comment: I forgot about the leading slash but `^\./[0-9].*` would work. I think using a regex makes the command more complicated than it needs to be. Using `-name` with a shell globbing pattern should be sufficient, e.g., `find . -name '[0-9]*'`. The advantage of using `find` over slm’s excellent answer is that it could be used recursively (though that isn’t relevant to this specific question).